# Dual Routing to support two MVC patterns for PHP

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing, legacy-code

I have a legacy framework that is php <= 5.3.2 approx with MySQL 5.2.1 (real legacy here) - that is not even PSR-0 compliance.

My goal is to transition out of the framework BUT there are over 1000 files involved - so recoding it for now is not an option.

So my solution for now is to have two fold routing:

Step 1: if routing matches - use framework 1 (consider Laravel)
step 2: if routing doesn't match - use legacy framework.

This way - anything that is "new" that is to be develop we can use the newer framework's feature - while still operating the old one until we can phase it out eventually.

My question now is: what is the proper way to have the newer framework be the dominant framework and have the legacy be the fall back so that eventually when i've transictioned 75% of the code I'll just display a 404 at that point.

The Legacy routing is:
/controller/action
so for each route - there must be a controller and action function then if needed queries.
What this means is that the routing is dependent on a controller / action and an associated view (ie you make a controller name foo, action bar, to get foo/bar) in comparison to Laravel where you can specify routing aliases and then associate a controller/action to it (ie if you create a controller and several functions - you dont necessary gain controller/action routing without editing the routes.php)

The legacy code has an index.php with a reference to a bootstrap that looks for class to load and environment configuration variables.

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing the same and considered a few solutions, though I don't understand what you mean by 'The Legacy routing is: /controller/action'.

I would say the best way to have Laravel the more dominant is have all requests go through Laravel and at the end of the routes.php have a catch all route e.g.

```
Route::any('{all}', function($uri)
{
    // Do stuff
})->where('all', '.*');
```

In the catch all you would want to load the legacy routing, this might involve includes or whatever.

By doing this your app runs through all your Laravel routes, and if none of them match it assumes its a legacy route.

The downside with doing it this way would be that all your requests for the legacy code are loading Laravel unnecessarily.

Alternative solutions would be using htaccess to either load legacy or laravel (works best if your site does not have SEO friendly URLs) or putting logic in the app/start/global.php to decide if this request should continue loading Laravel or load legacy.

Hope this helps, feel free to post more information

Comment: hi - thanks for your input. I have updated the question to explain the "legacy routing" in comparison to laravel. changing the .htaccess is a messy ordeal and it would be best to avoid that. 
With the added information about the legacy code - can you elaborate your root a bit more. tks.

Comment: Based on the legacy routing info I would say you should include the index.php that references the bootstrap and loads the class etc, should be very simple, but as I said above, this would mean you are loading Laravel with every request, if I'm guessing you are looking at an extra .4s on every request (complete guess)

Comment: what kind of logic would you put inside the app/start/global in order to prevent laravel to be used from a legacy stand point considering you need the routing to resolve if its legacy or not.

Comment: that is a tough one, when I was looking for my own project I could see if a file existed, one method could be telling if a controller exists with a method, if so use legacy and die, else continue. I don't think the time will be too significant, but if your site needs to be as fast as possible this is worth being aware of.

If you want to use the same routes for Laravel as the legacy and the Laravel route to overwrite the legacy, its probably best to have your include logic in routes.php

Comment: in other words - if you know your old routing was /controller/action you check if controller actually existed (ie legacy) and just die and use legacy instead rather than laravel - which prevents laravel from loading first and rather make laravel the backburner instead in this case despite having laravel be the first thing it check

Comment: Bingo, but this will mean your legacy is dominant over laravel (legacy routes overwrite laravel routes), way around this ofcourse is to use different urls for laravel.

Answer (score -1):

If it is possible to have a URI trick it would help you a lot. Something like:

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'-'), function() {

 Route::get('/new-framework-route', 'NewController@action');

});
```

so any request starting with a `-` would go to the new framework, i.e. `/-/users/` etc. Otherwise the legacy framework would handle it.

Comment: this would not work as i would be stuck to have weird URI in my new frameworks.

Comment: you can then change the prefix to be anything of your choice, if that's an option.